# nginx 403 Forbidden

Tags: nginx

Есть сайт и admin панель - все нормально работало,но когда я удалил из var/www/MySite/admin папку admin,а потом вернул ее, Админка перестала не работать с ошибкой 403 Forbidden

Конфиги не менял ,nginx перезапускал ,но ничего не работает((
Хелп

Comment: Читайте в логе ошибок конкретную причину появления ошибки 403

Comment: Проверьте права доступа к файлам линукс. ls -la - от кого созданы файлы. Возможно Вы сидите под пользователем root, а nginx работает под www-data. Можно ввести команду chown www-data:www-data ./ -R в корне проекта и посмотреть, станут ли файлы доступны

Comment: Сейчас попробусю,спасибо

Comment: @Veniamin Действительно проблема была в этом, благодарю)